# On-screen keyboard does not appear in many apps

Tags: ubuntu, fedora, gnome, touch-screen

Using the PC in tablet mode, I would like to use the virtual keyboard, but it does not appear in many apps including chrome and firefox. Basically it works only in the terminal and in nautilus. I'm on fedora 29 and this problem occurs both on (xorg and wayland). 
Ps I tried on my secondary system, on ubuntu, and there it also works on third-party apps